# How to create Espresso androidTest.apk out side of Android Studio environment?

Tags: android, github, jenkins, android-espresso

I have Jenkins job that gets the source code out of GitHub and creates release APK.
I would like to include in this job the creation of androidTest.apk, so I would upload it together with the release APK to test Environment like Google Test Lab and run Espresso tests.
I have managed to run gradlew assembleDebugAndroidTest, but first it is Debug and not release and second it didn't have my latest test, only old test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create Espresso androidTest.apk out side of Android Studio environment?

Navigate to your project directory and execute this in terminal:

```
./gradlew assembleAndroidTest
```

This will create instrumented debug apk.

To run instrumented tests perform:

```
./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest
```

or

```
./gradlew connectedCheck
```

Comment: running: ./gradlew assembleAndroidTest results in creating the debug-androidTest.apk, but it failed to run: ./gradlew assembleReleaseAndroidTest results with: Task 'assembleReleaseAndroidTest' not found in project. Do I need to do something to create this task?
is it because I ran my tests in debug and not release before I check-in the code? where should I find more reading on this subject?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. There is no `assembleReleaseAndroidTest`. I mixed with `assembleReleaseUnitTest`. Will edit my answer.